# Delete asset with GEE API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

In the Python API of GEE, is it possible to delete a known asset ?

I can crawl in but don't know how to delete one :

```py
assets = ee.data.listAssets({'parent': folder})

for asset in assets: 
    # something like 
    if asset.description = 'toto':
        asset.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete asset from earth engine API knowing the assetID, you have 2 solutions :

### CLI

in you terminal

```
earthengine rm users/username/asset_id
```

### Python

in your python file or notebook

```py
ee.data.deleteAsset('users/username/asset_id')
```